# Boost Python converter for std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, converting, boost

I could not find a Boost Python converter which converts `std::tuple`, so I wrote one.

This was tested with a g++ 4.7 snapshot on Debian squeeze. It uses C++ 11 features,
specifically variadic templates, so requires a recent compiler. This is based on [the answer to ""unpacking" a tuple to call a matching function pointer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7858971/350713).

It is rather long, and could probably be improved/simplified. In particular, the two *_wrapper structures look redundant.  How do I replace the `cpptuple2pytuple_wrapper` and `pytuple2cpptuple_wrapper` with one struct, and perhaps template on the differences using
something like type traits, if that is possible? Any other simplifications would also be interesting.

## cpptup_conv_pif.cpp

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

#include <boost/python/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/python/extract.hpp>
#include <boost/python/object.hpp>
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/class.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
using boost::python::extract;

template<int ...> struct seq{};
template<int N, int ...S> struct gens : gens<N-1, N-1, S...>{};
template<int ...S> struct gens<0, S...> {typedef seq<S...> type;};

template <typename ...Args>
struct cpptuple2pytuple_wrapper
{
  std::tuple<Args...> params;
  cpptuple2pytuple_wrapper(const std::tuple<Args...>& _params):params(_params){}

  boost::python::tuple delayed_dispatch()
  {
    return callFunc(typename gens<sizeof...(Args)>::type());
  }

  template<int ...S>
  boost::python::tuple callFunc(seq<S...>)
  {
    return boost::python::make_tuple(std::get<S>(params) ...);
  }
};

template <typename ...Args>
struct pytuple2cpptuple_wrapper
{
  boost::python::tuple params;
  pytuple2cpptuple_wrapper(const boost::python::tuple& _params):params(_params){}

  std::tuple<Args...> delayed_dispatch()
  {
    return callFunc(typename gens<sizeof...(Args)>::type());
  }

  template<int ...S>
  std::tuple<Args...> callFunc(seq<S...>)
  {
    return std::make_tuple((static_cast<Args>(extract<Args>(params[S])))...);
  }
};

// Convert (C++) tuple to (Python) tuple as PyObject*.
template<typename ... Args> PyObject* cpptuple2pytuple(const std::tuple<Args...>& t)
{
  cpptuple2pytuple_wrapper<Args...> wrapper(t);
  boost::python::tuple bpt = wrapper.delayed_dispatch();
  return boost::python::incref(boost::python::object(bpt).ptr());
}

// Convert (Python) tuple to (C++) tuple.
template<typename ... Args> std::tuple<Args...> pytuple2cpptuple(PyObject* obj)
{
  boost::python::tuple tup(boost::python::borrowed(obj));
  pytuple2cpptuple_wrapper<Args...> wrapper(tup);
  std::tuple<Args...> bpt = wrapper.delayed_dispatch();
  return bpt;
}

template<typename ... Args>
struct cpptuple_to_python_tuple
{
  static PyObject* convert(const std::tuple<Args...>& t)
    {
      return cpptuple2pytuple<Args...>(t);
    }
};

template<typename ... Args>
struct cpptuple_from_python_tuple
{
  cpptuple_from_python_tuple()
  {
    boost::python::converter::registry::push_back(
                          &convertible,
                          &construct,
                          boost::python::type_id<std::tuple<Args...> >());
  }

  static void* convertible(PyObject* obj_ptr)
  {
    if (!PyTuple_CheckExact(obj_ptr)) return 0;
    return obj_ptr;
  }

  static void construct(
            PyObject* obj_ptr,
            boost::python::converter::rvalue_from_python_stage1_data* data)
  {
    void* storage = (
             (boost::python::converter::rvalue_from_python_storage<std::tuple<Args...> >*)
             data)->storage.bytes;
    new (storage) std::tuple<Args...>(pytuple2cpptuple<Args...>(obj_ptr));
    data->convertible = storage;
  }
};

template<typename ...Args> void create_tuple_converter()
{
  boost::python::to_python_converter<std::tuple<Args...>, cpptuple_to_python_tuple<Args...> >();
  cpptuple_from_python_tuple<Args...>();
}

void export_cpptuple_conv()
{
  create_tuple_converter<int, float>();
  create_tuple_converter<int, double, string>();
}

std::tuple<int, float> tupid1(std::tuple<int, float> t){return t;}
std::tuple<int, double, string> tupid2(std::tuple<int, double, string> t){return t;}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(bptuple)
{
  export_cpptuple_conv();
  boost::python::def("tupid1", tupid1);
  boost::python::def("tupid2", tupid2);
}
```

This can be compiled with the following SConstruct file.

## SConstruct

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import commands, glob, os

def pyversion():
        pystr = commands.getoutput('python -V')
        version = pystr.split(' ')[1]
        major, minor = version.split('.')[:2]
        return major + '.' + minor

boost_python_env = Environment(
        #CXX="g++",
        CXX="g++-4.7",
        CPPPATH=["/usr/include/python"+pyversion()],
        CXXFLAGS="-ftemplate-depth-100 -fno-strict-aliasing -ansi -Wextra -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused-function -g -O3 -std=c++11",
        CPPDEFINES=['BOOST_PYTHON_DYNAMIC_LIB'],
        LIBPATH=["/usr/lib/python"+pyversion()+"/config"],
        LIBS=["python"+pyversion(), "m", "boost_python"],
        SHLIBPREFIX="", #gets rid of lib prefix
        )

boost_python_env.SharedLibrary(target="bptuple", source=["cpptup_conv_pif.cpp"])
```

The compilation looks like this on my machine:

> ```
> g++-4.7 -o cpptup_conv_pif.os -c -ftemplate-depth-100 -fno-strict-aliasing -ansi -Wextra -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused-function -g -O3 -std=c++11 -fPIC -DBOOST_PYTHON_DYNAMIC_LIB -I/usr/include/python2.6 cpptup_conv_pif.cpp
> g++-4.7 -o bptuple.so -shared cpptup_conv_pif.os -L/usr/lib/python2.6/config -lblitz -lRmath -lpython2.6 -lm -lboost_python
> ```

Usage:

> ```
> In [1]: import bptuple
>
> In [2]: bptuple.tupid1((1,1.2))
> Out[2]: (1, 1.2000000476837158)
>
> In [3]: bptuple.tupid2((1,1.2, "foo"))
> Out[3]: (1, 1.2, 'foo')
> ```

Answer (score 3):

One thing that's not immediately clear to me is if the `tuple2tuple_wrapper`'s are supposed to be internal helpers, or actually part of the interface. They seem to be instantiated only once each in the code shown, both immediately followed by a call to their `delayed_dispatch`.

If these are only internal helpers, you could trim them down a lot. You'll still need a templated struct with a templated member function, since you have two template parameter packs. But you're not actually using `delayed_dispatch` as it's name suggests, so that can go. And then the `params` member and ctor can go as well, with `params` becoming an extra parameter to `callFunc`. Taking `cpptuple2pytuple_wrapper` as an example:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct cpp_to_py_wrapper { // I suck at typing typle
    template<int... S>
    boost::python::tuple callFunc(std::tuple<Args...> params, seq<S...>) {
        return boost::python::make_tuple(std::get<S>(params)...);
    }
};
```

`cpptuple2pytuple` then becomes:

```
template<typename ... Args> PyObject* cpptuple2pytuple(const std::tuple<Args...>& t)
{
    boost::python::tuple bpt = cpp_to_py_wrapper<Args...>().callFunc(t, typename gens<sizeof...(Args)>::type());
    return boost::python::incref(boost::python::object(bpt).ptr());
}
```

Now you're just left with two instances of `callFunc`, both of which show a similar composition. If we just abstract for a bit:

```
template<int ...S>
return_type callFunc(params_type params, seq<S...>)
{
    return construct_tuple<return_type>(extract_tuple_value<S, Args>(params) ...);
}
```

Now, this is definitely something that can be implemented generically. However, if you're only using this here, I'd actually advise against it. Since you're only defining two conversions, hardcoding both overloads of `callFunc` will likely be *less* work than providing suitable implementations of `construct_tuple` and `extract_tuple_value`. A generic implementation will likely not pay off until you want to convert between more than three types. That's the point were the number of pair-wise combinations of N elements starts to grow faster than N itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Daan. Unfortunately, I don't remember this question that well - it has been a while. Working code would be helpful. I'm not sure what you mean by `typle2tuple` - there is no such name in my code.

Comment: That should have been t*u*ple. I was referring to `cpptuple2pytuple_wrapper` and it's counterpart. As for the working code: like I said, I don't have a compatible build environment. So unless you can provide a self-contained drop of your code, I can't even test what I've written so far ;-)

Comment: Define self-contained drop. I think if you cut and paste the code it will probably work. And I'm not sure what you  mean by "compatible build environment". Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, all that is rather central to testing the example. :-) What is your OS/distribution?

Comment: I use Debian wheezy. It's trivial to get all that stuff on Ubuntu. Try libboost-python-dev, scons, python-all-dev, g++. That would pull in most of it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to simplify this by using only a single wrapper template.  First, here's the single template:

```
template <typename P, typename R, typename ...Args>
struct tupleconvert_wrapper
{
  P params;
  tupleconvert_wrapper(const P& _params):params(_params){}

  R delayed_dispatch()
  {
    return callFunc(typename gens<sizeof...(Args)>::type());
  }

  template<int ...S, typename = typename std::enable_if<(sizeof(S),std::is_same<boost::python::tuple, R>::value), R>::type>
  boost::python::tuple callFunc(seq<S...>)
  {
    return boost::python::make_tuple(std::get<S>(params) ...);
  }

  template<int ...S, typename = typename std::enable_if<(sizeof(S),std::is_same<boost::python::tuple, P>::value), R>::type>
  std::tuple<Args...> callFunc(seq<S...>)
  {
    return std::make_tuple((static_cast<Args>(extract<Args>(params[S])))...);
  }
};
```

Here are the uses of it, as converted from your original code.

```
// Convert (C++) tuple to (Python) tuple as PyObject*.
template<typename ... Args> PyObject* cpptuple2pytuple(const std::tuple<Args...>& t)
{
  tupleconvert_wrapper<std::tuple<Args...>, boost::python::tuple, Args...> wrapper(t);
  boost::python::tuple bpt = wrapper.delayed_dispatch();
  return boost::python::incref(boost::python::object(bpt).ptr());
}

// Convert (Python) tuple to (C++) tuple.
template<typename ... Args> std::tuple<Args...> pytuple2cpptuple(PyObject* obj)
{
  boost::python::tuple tup(boost::python::borrowed(obj));
  tupleconvert_wrapper<boost::python::tuple, std::tuple<Args...>, Args...> wrapper(tup);
  std::tuple<Args...> bpt = wrapper.delayed_dispatch();
  return bpt;
}
```

You may be wondering why the `sizeof(S)` is part of the `std::enable_if` clause.  It's needed to force the `enable_if` to be dependent on the template parameter.  Otherwise your compiler will issue an error as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964447/why-compile-error-with-enable-if?rq=1).